# How to suppress typesetting of section title?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I would like to suppress the typesetting of the section title in the document *altogether*, but still setting it for purposes of subsections, section mark / header, and table of contents.

What I tried already:

```
\section[MySection]{}
```

Still displays the section number.

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\section[MySection]{}
```

Removes the section number, but also removes it from subsection numbers and TOC. Besides, I still get a vertical space where the section title had been.

I *could* do (and have done so far):

```
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0pt}{\vspace{-whatever_the_height_of_section_title}}
```

But it struck me as a bit ugly to "guess" the height of the section title (and having to re-guess if font sizes change). If there is some constant, like `\sectionfontheight` or somesuch, that would be a start.

But isn't there some "correct" way to set a section title "blindly", i.e. without actually printing it in the document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\nosection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \markright{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\nosection{First}
\subsection{What?}

\nosection{Second}
\subsection{Right}

\end{document}
```

`\refstepcounter` sets the number and resets the `subsection` counter; `\addcontentsline` does its usual job; `\markright` sets the heading's contents.

Comment: Brilliant. It never occurred to me that I could approach the problem from the other direction (emulating everything `\section` does *except* the actual typesetting), instead of trying to suppress the typesetting of `\section`. Replacing `\arabic{section}` (section number w/o chapter) with `\thesection` (chapter.section) made it fit my needs 100%. Thank you - It would've probably taken me ages to figure out the `\addcontentsline` myself, even if the basic idea had struck.

Comment: Note that this seems to have problems with switching between one- and two-column mode: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227328/remove-section-titles-from-text-but-not-table-of-contents-interaction-with-c