# Remove section titles from text, but not table of contents -- interaction with columns

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, two-column

*Update:* a previous version of this question wrongly attributed the problem to use of [`minitoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) to get section-level tables of contents (`\secttoc`).

I've got a complicated document with a tables of content, and which switches between one and two-column mode.

I'd like to remove the **sub**section headings themselves from the text, but leave them in the TOCs.

I tried the [recipe from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29261/how-to-suppress-typesetting-of-section-title):

```
\newcommand{\nosubsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
  \markright{#1}}
```

This *almost* works, but the TOCs comes out wrong. I.E.,

```
1 first section
   1.1 first sub
     1.1.1 first subsub
     1.1.2 second subsub
     1.2.1 first subsub    % <--- WRONG
   1.2 second sub
```

but should really be

```
1 first section
   1.1 first sub
     1.1.1 first subsub
     1.1.2 second subsub
   1.2 second sub
     1.2.1 first subsub
```

I think this is due to a strange interaction with the switching between one- and two-column mode: the first subsubsection in each subsection are put in the subsection above where they belong. This happens even when I just to include the supposedly do-nothing `\onecolumn\twocolumn`.

Here's an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (or actually, a minimal *failing* example):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcommand{\nosubsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
  \markright{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{first section---show all subs 1---works}
\subsection{first sub 1.1}
\twocolumn[{\subsubsection{first subsub 1.1.1}}]
\twocolumn[{\subsubsection{second subsub 1.1.2}}]
\subsection{second sub 1.2}
\twocolumn[{\subsubsection{first subsub 1.2.1}}]

\section{second section--don't show subs 2 --- fails}
\nosubsection{first sub 2.1} %\label{sub:2.1}
\twocolumn[{\subsubsection{first subsub 2.1.1}}]
\twocolumn[{\subsubsection{second subsub 2.1.2}}]
\onecolumn  %%%% these casuse the problem, I think
\twocolumn
\nosubsection{second sub 2.2}
\twocolumn[{\subsubsection{first subsub 2.2.1 \textbf{WRONG}}}]

\end{document}
```

(Note that you need both `nosubsection` *and* column-switching to get the failure.)

I *have* also tried using the `multicol` package, and I get the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` to help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PierPaolo, yes, thanks for the admonition. The very fact that I can't do that easily implies that the problem is some ugly interaction between the macros in my document (I suspect `includeonly` and `import`, but I can't trace it very far. Aaargh!

Comment: @PierPaolo: much changed now (just adding comment so that you notice it -- sorry!)

Comment: Please, make a sensible example: `\onecolumn` immediately followed by `\twocolumn` means nothing.

Comment: @egreg: this is the *minimal* working example. Feel free to insert any text between those; it will still fail!

Comment: No, I won't. This switching between one and two columns is wrong to begin with. You probably want to use the `multicol` package.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't mean to actually do that; I meant that the problem doesn't depend on what goes there. Isn't using `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` a legit way to switch between columns? If so, this should work, right?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe From what I saw, this is a problem of timing with respect to the annotation made by `\addcontentsline` in the `.aux` file. The note is written only at shipout time, probably the switches make the note to be written at the wrong time. And, no, switching between one and two column should not be done in this way.

Comment: Would using `\multicols` fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of the `\subsection` heading is (see macro `\@sect` in `latex.ltx` for example)

```
\begingroup 
  #6{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
    \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
\endgroup
```

If this should not appear when the section level is `subsection`, it could be patched to use a `\ifstrequal` for testing if `#1` is equal to `subsection`.

I added the `\begin{multicols}{2}...\end{multicols}` wrappers as well.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \begingroup 
  #6{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
    \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
  \endgroup
}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{subsection}{%
    % Do nothing here!
  }{%
    \begingroup
    #6{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
      \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}{\typeout{successful patching}}{\typeout{Nope}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{first section---show all subs 1---works}
\subsection{first sub 1.1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsubsection{first subsub 1.1.1}
\blindtext[2]
\subsubsection{second subsub 1.1.2}
\blindtext[2]

\end{multicols}
\subsection{second sub 1.2}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \subsubsection{first subsub 1.2.1}
\blindtext[5]

\end{multicols}

\section{second section--don't show subs 2 --- works now}
\subsection{first sub 2.1} %\label{sub:2.1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsubsection{first subsub 2.1.1}
\blindtext[10]

\subsubsection{second subsub 2.1.2}
\blindtext[5]

\end{multicols}
\subsection{second sub 2.2}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsubsection{first subsub 2.2.1 \textbf{CORRECT}}
\blindtext[5]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]